# fetch pages [LWP] parse them [HTML::TokeParser] and store results [DBI]

Tags: html-parsing, store, lwp

A triple job: I have to do a job with tree task. We have three tasks:

1. Fetch pages
2. Parse HTML
3. Store data... And yes - this is a true Perl-job!

I have to do a parser-job on all 6000 sub-pages of a site in suisse. (a governmental site - which has very  good servers ).

see   http://www.educa.ch/dyn/79362.asp?action=search and
(if you do not see **approx 6000 results** - then do a search with *.*

A **detailed page** is like this:

[link text][1]

- Ecole nouvelle de la Suisse Romande
  Ch. de Rovéréaz 20 Case postal 161
  1000  Lausanne 12 Website 
  info@ensr.ch Tel:021 654 65 00
  Fax:021 654 65 05

another detailed pages shows this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta name="generator" content="DigiOnline GmbH - WebWeaver 3.4 CMS - "><title>educa.ch</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="101.htm"><script src="102.htm"></script><script language="JavaScript"><!--
var did='d79376';
var root=new Array('d200','d205','d73137','d1566','d79376','d');
var usefocus = 1;
function check() {
if ((self.focus) && (usefocus)) {
self.focus();
}
}
// --></script></head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="check();"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%"><tr><td width="15" class="popuphead"><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="16"></td><td width="99%" class="popuphead">Adresse - Schulen in der Schweiz</td><td width="20" class="popuphead" valign="middle"><a href="#" title="Print" onclick="window.print(); return false;"><img src="../pics/print16x13.gif" alt="Drucken" width="16" height="13"></a></td><td width="20" class="popuphead" valign="middle"><a href="#" title="close" onclick="window.close(); return false;"><img src="../pics/close21x13.gif" alt="Schliessen" width="21" height="13"></a></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#B2B2B2"><td colspan="4"><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1"></td></tr></table><div class="leerzeile">&#160;</div><div class="leerzeile"><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8">Auseklis - Schule für lettische Sprache und Kultur</div><div class="leerzeile">&#160;</div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8">Mutschellenstrasse 37</div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8"></div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8">8002&#160;Zürich</div><div class="leerzeile">&#160;</div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8"><a href="http://latvia.yourworld.ch" target="_blank">latvia.yourworld.ch</a></div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8"><a href="mailto: schorderet@inbox.lv">schorderet@inbox.lv</a></div><div class="leerzeile">&#160;</div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8">Tel:<img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="6" height="8">+41786488637</div><div><img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="15" height="8">Fax:<img src="/0.gif" alt="" width="4" height="8"></div><div>&#160;</div></body></html>
```

I want to do this job with ** HTML::TokeParser or HTML::TokeParser** or **HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML ** but i have little experience with HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML

Which one would you prefer for this job: Note  - I want to store the results in a MySQL-DB. Best things would be to store it immitiately after parsing:

so we have **three tasks:**

1. Fetch pages
2. Parse HTML
3. Store data

**First item:** Use LWP::UserAgent to fetch. There are many examples in this forum of using that module to post data and get the resulting pages. BTW we  can use Mechanize instead if we prefer.

**Second:** Parse the page as eg with HTML::TokeParser or some other module to get at only the data we need.

**Third:** Store the data straight away into a database. There is no need to take an intermediate step and write a temporary file.

hmmm -  the first and the second question - how to fetch and how to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be too specific as your question is very general. I've retrieved pages using LWP and used TokeParser to extract data and store the output in a database many times. I haven't used Mech, but by all accounts it is simpler than LWP.

Creating a user agent using LWP can be as simple as:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
```

you will need to consider things like re-directs, proxies and cookies or passwords depending on your requirements.

To follow re-directs:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    requests_redirectable =>   ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST' ]
);
```

To store cookies:

```
$ua->cookie_jar( {} );
```

To set up a proxy:

```
$ua->proxy("http", "http://localhost:8888");  # Fiddler
```

To add a password for authentication:

```
$ua->credentials( 'www.myhostingplace.com:443' , 'Realm' , 'userid', 'password');
```

To get content from a page for local processing:

```
$url = 'http://www.someurl.com'
my $response  = $ua->get($url);
if ( $response->is_error() ) {
   # Do some error stuff
}
my $content = $response->content();
```

To parse the content using TokeParser:

```
my $stream = new HTML::TokeParser(\$content);

while ( my $t = $stream->get_token() ) {
   if ( $t->[0] eq 'S' and $t->[1] eq 'input' ) {
      if ( uc( $t->[2]{ 'name' } ) eq 'SEARCHVALUE' ) {
           my $data = $t->[2]{ 'value' };
           # Do something with data
      }
   }
}
```

The data is passed into TokeParser as a reference; I then walk through the stream using get token. Each HTML element is passed into an array which you can examine to determine what you should do next.

In the above example I want to search for input tags with an attribute name of 'SEARCHVALUE' and then store the 'value' attribute. The HTML fragment might look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SEARCHVALUE" value="Spock" />
```

When I hit the start of the input tag ($t->[0] eq 'S' and $t->[1] eq 'input') I examine the "name" attribute of the tag (t->[2]{ 'name' }) to see if it matches the value I am searching for; if it does I store the value attribute of the tag ($t->[2]{ 'value' }) in a variable. I can then do whatever I like with the value including storing it in a database.

You can do a lot with TokeParser and in some cases it can be simpler than using regular expressions to carve up the page but it can also be a little challenging to get your head around. If you are trying to extract a simple pattern from the return HTML content then a regular expression can be just as good.

If you have a lot of this to do then I recommend "Perl and LWP" by Sean Burke from O'Reilly. It has been endlessly helpful for me in my web scraping endeavours.

Hope this helps you get started at least.

Comment: Hello Auctionitis, Many thanks for the reply. This helps me to get started. And yes: I have ordered the book "Perl and LWP" by Sean Burke allready. A great tipp! Note - i have lots of this to do. - i will come up  with more questions and stuff - but now i first will do some exercises. Untill soon! Regards

Comment: hello Auctionitis - again thanks for the message and your great hints. btw - i have made some more efforts - can you help me to debug. Love to hear from you  - see  the code to debug! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007480/applying-a-loop-on-lwpuseragent-to-fetch-1000-pages-at-once - love to hear from you. martin