# How can I use Perl's LWP::UserAgent to fetch the same URL with different query strings?

Tags: perl, loops, lwp-useragent

I have a running LWP::UserAgent that should be applied on following URL:

```
http://dms-schule.bildung.hessen.de/suchen/suche_schul_db.html?show_school=5503
```

This runs with many many similar targets see the following endings:

```
html?show_school=5503
html?show_school=9002
html?show_school=5512
```

I want to do this with use LWP::UserAgent:

```
for my $i (0..10000) 

{ $ua->get(' [here the URL should be applied] ', id => 21, extern_uid => $i); 
# process reply }
```

In any case, using a loop like this for that kind of job is a way to do it. I guess the LWP's API does not aim to replace the functionality of the core Perl, and I can use Perl loops to query multiple URLs.

The code that does not run because the loop has to be applied:

```
#use strict;

use DBI;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

# first get a list of all schools
my ($url = '[here the url should be applied] =',id);

for my $id (0..10000) {
  $ua->get(' [here the url should be applied ] ', id => 21, extern_uid => $i);
  # process reply
}  

#my $request = POST $url,
#                 [
#         Schulsuche=> "Ergebnisse anzeigen",
#         order => "schule_ort",
#         schulname => undef, 
#         schulort => undef, 
#         typid => "11",
#         verbinder => "AND"
#                 ];

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
print "getting all schools - this could take some time\n";
my $response = $ua->request($request);

# extract the ids
my @ids = $response->content =~ /getSchoolDetail\((\d+)/gs;
print "found " . scalar @ids . " schools\n";

# for this demo we only do the first 5
my @ids_to_do = @ids[0..4];

# use your own user and password
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=schulen", "user", "pass", { AutoCommit => 0 }) or die $!;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<sqlend);
   insert into schulen ( name , plz , ort, strasse , tel, fax , mail, quelle , original_id )
               values  ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
sqlend

# now loop over ids
for my $id (@ids_to_do) {

  # get detail information for id
  my $res = $ua->get("[url]=> &gid=$id");

  # parse the response
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
  $tree->parse($res->content);

  my $xpath = q|//div[@id='MCinhview']//div[@class='contentitem']//table|;
  my ($adress_table, $tel_table) = $tree->findnodes($xpath);

  my ($adr) = $adress_table->find("td");
  my ($name, $city, $street) = map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; $_ } ($adr->content_list)[2,4,6];

  my($plz, $ort) = $city =~ /^(\d+)\s*(.*)/;
  my ($tel, $fax, $mail) = map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; $_ } map { ($_->content_list)[1] } $tel_table->find("td");

  $sth->execute($name, $plz, $ort, $street, $tel, $fax, $mail, "SA", $id);
  $dbh->commit;

  $tree->delete;

  print "$name done\n";
}
```

---

**update on sunday october 25 th:** I have applied the advice from OmnipotentEntity.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use strict;
use warnings;         # give out some warnings if something does not run well
use diagnostics;      # tell me when something is wrong 
use DBI;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

# first get a list of all schools

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7"); 

#pretending to be firefox on linux.

for my $i (0..10000) {
  my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => sprintf(" here to put the URL into =%d", $i));
  $request->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
  my $response = $ua->request($request);
  if ($response->is_success) {
    $pagecontent = $response -> content;
  }
# now we can do whatever with the $pagecontent

}
my $request = POST $url,
[
          order => "schule_ort",
          schulname => undef, 
          Basisdaten => undef,        
          Profil  => undef, 
          Schulort => undef, 
          typid => "11",
          Fax  => 
          Homepage  => undef, 
          verbinder => "AND"

];

print "getting all schools - this could take some time\n";
my $response = $ua->request($request);

# extract the ids
my @ids = $response->content =~ /getSchoolDetail\((\d+)/gs;
print "found " . scalar @ids . " schools\n";

# for this demo we only do the first 5
my @ids_to_do = @ids[0..4];

# use your own user and password
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=schulen", "user", "pass", { AutoCommit => 0 }) or die $!;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<sqlend);
   insert into schulen ( name , plz , ort, strasse , tel, fax , mail, quelle , original_id )
               values  ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
sqlend

# now loop over ids
for my $id (@ids_to_do) {

  # get detail information for id
  my $res = $ua->get(" here to put the URL into => &gid=$id");

  # parse the response
  my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;
  $tree->parse($res->content);

  my $xpath = q|//div[@id='MCinhview']//div[@class='floatbox']//table|;
  my ($adress_table, $tel_table) = $tree->findnodes($xpath);

  my ($adr) = $adress_table->find("td");
  my ($name, $city, $street) = map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; $_ } ($adr->content_list)[2,4,6];

  my($plz, $ort) = $city =~ /^(\d+)\s*(.*)/;
  my ($tel, $fax, $mail) = map { s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; $_ } map { ($_->content_list)[1] } $tel_table->find("td");

  $sth->execute($name, $plz, $ort, $street, $tel, $fax, $mail, "SA", $id);
  $dbh->commit;

  $tree->delete;

  print "$name done\n";
}
```

I want to loop over the results and therefore I tried to apply the corresponding URLs but I got a bunch of errors:

```
suse-linux:/usr/perl # perl perl_mecha_example_two.pl
Global symbol "$pagecontent" requires explicit package name at perl_mecha_example_two.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$url" requires explicit package name at perl_mecha_example_two.pl line 29.
Execution of perl_mecha_example_two.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates 
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"), 
    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say 
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").

Uncaught exception from user code:
Global symbol "$pagecontent" requires explicit package name at perl_mecha_example_two.pl line 24.
Global symbol "$url" requires explicit package name at perl_mecha_example_two.pl line 29.
Execution of perl_mecha_example_two.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
at perl_mecha_example_two.pl line 86
```

Now the debugging part. What do I change? How to apply the URLs in the right way?

When I use strict I'm not allowed to use a variable before I declare it. The usual fix is to prepend `my`, e.g. `my $url` and `my $pagecontent` on the first appearance of it.

Comment: note: When you use strict; you are not allowed to use a variable before you declare it. Usual fix is to prepend my, e.g. my $url and my $pagecontent on the first appearance of it.

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7"); #pretending to be firefox on linux.
for my $i (0..10000) {
  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => sprintf("http://path/to/url?=%d", $i));
  $req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
  my $res = $ua->request($req);
  if ($res->is_success) {
    $pagecontent = $res -> content;
  }
# Do whatever with the $pagecontent
}
```

This is assuming you want to fetch all 10000 pages.  If you only want to fetch particular ones then you should try throwing those numbers in an array, and then have for walk that array, rather than 1..10000

Comment: Hi! Great to hear from you. Thx for the solution. Now, i will muse how i work out the array that collects the particular ones. I need to throw all into the array. See - for another example these two site... (out of a simmilar-Perl-job)
<br>
http://schulnetz.nibis.de/db/schulen/schule.php?schulnr=67003&lschb=<br>
http://schulnetz.nibis.de/db/schulen/schule.php?schulnr=67002&lschb=
<br>
note the first has results - the second has no values....
now i need to write the code for the arrays

Comment: Update: Hi OmnipotentEntity - thx for the message. I tried to apply and to run the script. But some errors occured. See more above. Now i have to debug the code... Would love to hear from you. regards martin